# How to insert a constraint on coefficients of logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, regularization, matlab

I want to build a logistic regression model on my data, which contains three continuous predictors and a logical response. I need to constrain the regression coefficients to be not less than 0 and sum up to a constant, i.e.,

$$y=\frac {1}{1+e^{-(\beta_1\times x_1+\beta_2 \times x_2+\beta_3 \times x_3)}}$$

$$s.t. \beta_j \geq 0(j=1,2,3)$$

$$ \beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3=1$$

Is there anyone who knows how to add such constraint in theory? And how can this be done in MATLAB? The following is my test code using the function '***glmfit***' which did not have an option to introduce a constraint:

```
load hospital.mat
dsa = hospital;

Age = dsa.Age;
Weight = dsa.Weight;
Blood = dsa.BloodPressure(:, 1);

Smoker = dsa.Smoker;

mdl = fitglm([Age, Weight, Blood], Smoker, 'Distribution', 'binomial', 'Intercept', false)
```

Comment: Sounds like nonlinear programming? In any event, we are all curious as to *why* you want to do this.

Comment: I want to use the fitted weights to weighing multiple models in model averaging of classifiers, in which the weights I assume to be nonnegative and constrained in the simplex space.

Comment: Ok, I guess you realize that classification will probably be worse when you constrain, but depending on sample size, perhaps not.

Comment: Thank you. I also guess the performance will decline if constraint was considered. But what does you mean by "...but depending on sample size, perhaps not"? It is not clear to me.

Comment: With small sample sizes, reasonable constraints often reduce variability and thus can provide more accurate estimates.